# Haskell non exhaustive patterns in function for recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail

It gives  multiple declaration of **"mPH"**

here is the code

```
dotProduct x y = sum(zipWith (*) x y)

matrixProduct x y = mPH [] x y

mPH acc [] b = acc

countHelp countacc c [] = countacc

countHelp countacc c (d:ds) = countHelp ((dotProduct c d) : countacc) c ds

mPH acc (a:as) b = mPH ((countHelp [] a b) : acc) as b
```

can anyone explain a little bit for me? 
Suppose my input will be

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
y = [[7,9,11],[8,10,12]]
matrixProduct x y
```

It should give back 
martix [[64,58],[154,139]]

what I think is each time I taking out first list of the first matrix when the the matrix become a empty list the recursion will stop.

Comment: Try putting the two lines defining `mPH` adjacent to each other in the code.

Comment: Use irc if you want timely advice.  Get countHelp below mPH, don't split up your mPH definition.

Comment: @Dubuisson what do you mean irc?

Comment: Ty you guys so much when i put the mPH definition together it work!!!

Comment: By [IRC](https://www.haskell.org/irc) he means the good old chat. Anyway, unless it's a very small thing and you can wait StackOverflow allows one to write more detailed answers.

Comment: @bheklilr, this is actually an answer rather than a comment.